# The difference between FragmentContainerView and fragment

Tags: android

I have two XML layouts behaving differently, with the only difference being that one makes use of the new

- `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`
  and another, the older:
- `<fragment`

In AndroidStudio, as seen in the attached photo, in the first case I don't see the layout. In the other layout, I do.

Is it an Android Studio 3.6.3 bug, or a definition matter, and how ?

[printscreen of the situation how i see it in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYKfj.jpg)

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.tasktimer.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/a_fragment_main"/>
```

Comment: Is this about the difference or the issue you're having? Your title seems to suggest one thing but your question another.